# Emberjs - model that changed in @each

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have an `ArrayController` which *observes* changes of a specific property of each model. I use the `.observes('content.@each.someprop')` for that purpose:

```
App.ListController = Em.ArrayController.extend({
    content: [],

    myObserver: function () {
        //check changed property
        //do stuff if changed to some specific value
    }.observes('content.@each.someprop')
});
```

So far so good - the observer fires when the property of any model changes. However, when it fires, I have no idea which model had changed - i have to iterate over models and compare that property with old values stored elsewhere to figure it out, which is very clumsy and inefficient. I tried to check the `arguments` that the observer receives, but they are also of no use: `console.log(arguments)` from within observer gives the following: `[Class, "content.@each.someprop"]`, and `console.log(arguments[0].toString())` gives `<App.ListController:ember366>` - the controller itself and the property string.

So my question is: is there a way to know which model has changed when observing the array's `@each` property?

#### Update

When observer fires, I want to check whether the watched property has changed to some specific value, and if so, do some stuff.

As suggested I will check the `itemController` now.

Comment: afaik, there is no common bucket where dirty records are pooled. Although that seems like a really useful thing to have.

Comment: @MehulKar bucket will be good too, but what i'm looking for is notification about model(s) whose change triggered the observer. If it could be done via function argument it would be the best..

Comment: Isn't this something you want to observe on the model, rather than the controller?

Comment: Looks like something you should observe or store on the model, or more likely, an itemClassController... What are you trying to accomplish with the observe?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this in current ember using [reduceComputed](http://emberjs.com/api/#method_reduceComputed) or [arrayComputed](http://emberjs.com/api/#method_arrayComputed).

It would be good to know your use case though: very likely there is a better approach than manually creating an observer.

Answer (score 0):

You can observer the property directly on the model where you can just access `this`. When you observer with `@each` you shouldn't really care that a specific record changed, just that something changed.

Using an `itemController` is an option as well, but it might be an overkill.